# get image post response from iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, file-upload

I'm using an iframe (colorbox) to show a form, where users will upload an image

On submit, the form submits and uploads the image and simply responds with the new URL of the image online.

Is there a way that I can capture this response via javascript and get the value into the parent window somehow? Ideally once the upload is complete, I want to close the iframe and then have this variable ready to use in my main window.

Thanks

Comment: You could add some JS to your iframe that triggers a function in your parent window when the upload is done.

Comment: `theiframe.onload = function...` once they're on the same domain/protcol/port (origin)

Comment: Thanks can you please put a quick example to help explain? @musa

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C64BH/